# Postman 403 Token Issue

Tags: postman

I am trying to get request with endpoint after successful login.
I achieved to be login and take the token but I could not take the list with this token. I am using postman. Whenever I click the url link i sent with token i can see the valid json with my safari.

```
{
    "message": "Forbidden"
}
```

> what i sent https://qo7vrra66k.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/products?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c

How can I send and successfully take this request from postman ? Also I couldnt understand why postman don`t allow this like safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your endpoint and got no error.

[image]

Comment: thank you I think my postmen settings are wrong, i achieved with new account